# How to plot a multiple line graph in R

Tags: r, plot

I have to create a plot with the number of COVID-19 confirmed cases by date, in each country. I have to use the data inside the package: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coronavirus/index.html.

I managed to create a subset with the variables "Country Region", "Type" (confirmed only), "date", and "total of cases". However, i don't know to plot a graph with multiple lines.

I have to plot a graph with all countries in it, based on the:
https://twitter.com/thomasfujiwara/status/1249817958874001412?s=20

I also want to exclude mainland china from the dataset

**Can someone help me?**

Comment: Can you shared the code you have used? How have you tried plotting your data so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to help without a reproducible example, but one way would be to use `ggplot2`. You can use either the `group` or the `color` aesthetic in your plot:

```
library(coronavirus)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(coronavirus)

coronavirus %>%
    filter(type == "confirmed") %>%
    filter(Country.Region != "Mainland China") %>% 
    group_by(Country.Region, date) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(cases)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = total, color = Country.Region)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I also wanted to know how can i remove "Mainland China", that is inside the variable Country.Region ?

Comment: Done. Edit your original question to include that as part of your question.